# shared_ptr and raw pointer to the same type in ternary operator

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a statement which uses a ternary operator which looks like this:

```
auto res = (test) ? test : func();
```

where test is a raw pointer to an element of type T while `func()` is a function which returns a `shared_ptr` to that type T, i.e. `shared_ptr<T>`.

The C++ compiler complains that as it is, this is not correct as they are two different types, so to make it work I am doing something like this `func().get()`, but I was wondering, what is the best way idiomatically in C++ to write that statement?

Comment: "What is the best way" to do *what*? What do you want the outcome to be? Do you want `res` to be raw pointer or `shared_ptr`? If former, who should keep ownership of `func()` result? If latter, do you want to give ownership over `test` to `res` or do you want it to manage a copy of what `test` points to?

Comment: For what this code needs to do, it's irrelevant if `res` is raw or `shared_ptr`, I was just wondering, in this kind of situation, in general, if idiomatically that should aim to get a raw pointer or a shared_ptr, i.e. if it's better to use a raw pointer if you don't have any specific reason to use a shared_ptr, or if on the other way round, that should try to preserve the shared_ptr typeness. Only thing sure is that the user of res doesn't need to transfer ownership of what it gets from `func`.

Comment: @ad3angel1s — it is **absolutely** relevant. There is no idiom that can determine whether this code should use a raw pointer or a shared pointer. That’s a **design decision**, and it’s answer depends on what the code is going to do with the pointer.

Comment: Runtime `auto`. That would be interesting. Break more than a bit of how C++ works, but interesting

Comment: If `test` is a compile-time constant expression and you're using C++17, you could use `if constexpr` instead of the ternary operator.

Comment: that code is just using `res` to call a method, that's why i am saying that it is irrelevant if `res` is shared_ptr or raw.

Comment: This is where we remind you to post a minimal, **complete**, verifiable code example.

Comment: @ad3angel1s In that case, a better answer to _"Do you want res to be raw pointer or shared_ptr?"_ is _"I just need to call a method through the pointer. (I don't care if `res` is raw or `shared_ptr`.)"_ That shows that some thought has been put into the answer.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is about federated ownership of an object.  `unique_ptr` is about sole ownership of an object.  My guidance is that a raw pointer (in modern C++) ought to be used only for a non-owning pointer.  So to answer your question would require knowing the ownership of the objects.

Comment: @ad3angel1s _"the user of res doesn't need to transfer ownership of what it gets from `func`."_ -- what guarantees that the returned pointer will remain valid in the calling code? If you do not have (shared) ownership, you have no way to keep the object alive. (Also, what guarantee do you have that `func()` will not return a null pointer?)

Comment: @user4581301 `std::any`

Answer (score 2):

You want to make auto res of either raw or shared pointer type, decided at runtime.
Static typing doesn't allow that.

One way is to emulate that with `std::variant`, but it would be clumsy.

Other could be using `shared_ptr` with null deleter, but it has performance impact for deleter block.

I can think of such solution as a practical one, still ugly though:

```
shared_ptr<T> storage;
auto res = (test) ? test : (storage = func(), storage.get());
```